# customized UISegmentControl does not work properly

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, uisegmentedcontrol

I wanted to customize UISegmentControl of my app and I used following codes:

```
UIImage *segmentSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_sel.png"];
UIImage *segmentUnselected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns.png"];
UIImage *segmentSelectedUnselected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_sel-uns.png"];
UIImage *segUnselectedSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns-sel.png"];
UIImage *segmentUnselectedUnselected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns-uns.png"];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselected
                                               forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentSelected
                                               forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentUnselectedUnselected
                                 forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                                   rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                                          barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentSelectedUnselected
                                 forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                                   rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                                          barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance]
     setDividerImage:segUnselectedSelected
     forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
     rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
     barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I got following pictures from my app

[image: First Picture]

[image: Second Picture]

[image: Third Picture]

[image: Forth Picture]

I used several methods to correct the problem like CGImages and Resizable Images but none of them worked! What is the problem and How should I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have look at the link below

http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/13/wooduinavigation/

and there is one demo code also available here

https://github.com/xhan/PlutoLand

Comment: Thanks for your help but it didn't change anything in app!